# How display only user name role in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to display the role in the view in ASP.NET Core. I log in to the application and I have info: Hi {User}, you have permission: {permission}.

How to do it? I was looking for various guides but there is nothing mentioned about it.

I tried with it:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using EarSystem.Models
@inject SignInManager<UserApp> Sign
@inject UserManager<UserApp> UserLog
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPanel.cshtml";
}
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div>
        <h1>Your Account:</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Login:</b><p>@UserLog.GetUserName(User)</p></li>
            <li>
                @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
                {
                    <b>Role:</b><p>@claim</p>
                }
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p></p>
}

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Result:

[image]

I need get result only user role these is underline on yellow color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to access current HttpContext and user in view. Then get all roles of user by using `UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user)`.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using EarSystem.Models
@inject SignInManager<UserApp> Sign
@inject UserManager<UserApp> UserLog

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPanel.cshtml";
}
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var user = await UserLog.GetUserAsync(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
    var roles = await UserLog.GetRolesAsync(user);
    <div>
        <h1>Your Account:</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Login:</b><p>@UserLog.GetUserName(User)</p></li>
            <li>
                @foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    <b>Role:</b><p>@role</p>
                }
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

In startup.cs `ConfigureServices`,register `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Make sure you've seeded the roles in the database and also the registered user is assigned a role.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
@{
  var roles = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
}
<li>
 @foreach (var claim in roles)
 {
     <b>Role:</b><p>@claim</p>
 }
```